# Django REST specify which fields when viewing a list

Tags: python, django, rest

By default, when asking a list of a model like "/cars", django rest outputs all of the model data. I want it to output only pk's on a list request, and full model data on a detail request. I am using ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet.

PS. Is it supposed to be like this by design? Pulling so much unneeded data seems like such a waste.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply override the 'list' method of viewset to get desired response like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pks = []
    qs = self.get_queryset()
    for obj in qs:
        pks.append(obj.pk)
    return Response(data=pks)
```

Answer (score 3):

I customized the code to suit my requirement. I created the following 2 mixins. Make your APIListView extend `FieldFilterMixin` and your serializer extend `SerializerFieldsMixin`. Pass fl in GET request with comma separated values to get the required fields in response.

```
class SerializerFieldsMixin(object):
    """
    Return only the fields asked for.
    Don't return any extra fields in serializer.
    """
    def get_fields(self):
        all_fields = super(SerializerFieldsMixin,self).get_fields()
        asked_fields = self.context.get('asked_fields')
        if not asked_fields:
            return all_fields
        all_fields = OrderedDict([(k,v) for k,v in all_fields.items() if k in asked_fields])
        return all_fields


class FieldFilterMixin(object):
    """
    To be used with List/Retrieve views.
    Set class attribute fields for the fields you want to display.
    Or override get_required_fields to customize.
    """

    def get_required_fields(self):
        if self.request.GET.has_key("fl"):
            return self.request.GET["fl"]
        return []

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        methods_to_act_on = ["GET","HEAD"]
        context = super(FieldFilterMixin,self).get_serializer_context()
        asked_fields = self.get_required_fields()
        if asked_fields and self.request.method in methods_to_act_on:
            context["asked_fields"] = asked_fields
        return context
```